# How to remove duplicate rows in shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Could you kindly support the below query,

How to do in shell script (.sh) ?

**cat inputFile.txt**

```
row1 x_1    8
row2 x_1    8     1
row3 x_2    6
row4 x_2    6     1
row5 x_3    5
row6 x_4    7
```

Step 1:
We have to remove the below rows from above file

```
x_1    8
x_2    6
```

Step 2:
We have to keep the below rows from above file

```
row2 x_1    8  1
row4 x_2    6  1
row5 x_3    5
row6 x_4    7
```

Expected output:

**cat outputFile.txt**

```
x_1    8     1
x_2    6     1
x_3    5
x_4    7
```

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: I've formatted the data for you (please look to see what I did).  The `rowN` information appears to be a line number rather than part of the data, or do you need to strip that from the data?  You say 'remove duplicate rows' — but is the 'duplicate-ness based on columns 1 & 2 (of the data with the `rowN` column removed)?  As written `row1 x_1 8` is not a duplicate of `row2 x_1 8 1`.  And do you need to preserve the first or the last or the longest row of the duplicates, or is there some other criterion that should be used?  (The sample output suggests 'last', but 'longest' can't be ruled out.)

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'rows', this means lines to me, like duplicate lines in a file.  I can't tell if when you posted that those x_1 8 1 x_2.. above were originally one per line.  So let's assume they were.  A neat trick to remove the duplicates is simply:

```
cat outputFile.txt | sort | uniq
```

You need to sort the lines first because uniq removes repeated lines which are adjacent.

If you really meant to remove duplicates within a line itself, an easy hack would be to put the words in the line into separate lines using something like `xargs -n 1` , then piping that to the `sort | uniq`, then put everything back on a single line with something like `tr '\n' ' '`:

```
cat outputFile.txt | xargs -n 1 | sort | uniq | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Now that you updated your question above, I don't think what i wrote is what you need.  It's not going to remove the lines unless they are clearly duplicates.

Comment: Try writing a script which loops over your input and greps your file for each line in the file and if it doesn't find anything, then echo it.